# Motion about black holes

Tags: black-holes

If possible, a particle performs circular motion about the centre of gravity of black hole. Will it be pulled inwards or it continues to move circular?

Comment: [How to Understand the Image of a Black Hole](https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2019/5/24/how-to-understand-the-image-of-a-black-hole)

Answer (score 2):

If it has enough velocity it will stay in orbit around the black hole. This orbit could be perfectly circular and the particle would not be pulled in. This is completely analogous to the earth orbiting around the sun. Indeed if we changed the sun into a black hole of the same mass, the earth's orbit would be unaffected.

Edit: As pointed out this is only true when your orbital radius is larger then 3 times the radius of the black hole. If you get to close other effects take over.

Comment: But earth doesn't orbit sun in circular motion.

Comment: You asked if it was possibly circular.  I said the orbit was possibly circular. It could also be elliptical depending on exactly what velocity and how far away you put the particle. Also the earth's orbit is closer to a circle then you think

Comment: Okay now got the idea, means you are saying that black hole's centre is also changing hence there can be a change in the path of the particle

Comment: No, I'm saying the eccentricity of a stable orbit can be anywhere from at least 0 (circular) to less then 1. 
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)

Comment: "perfectly circular" is funny expression in physics. Anyway, do you assume no angular momentum of the black hole? GR tends to complicate the orbits in this situation. I think with any nonzero angular momentum there is no possibility of perfectly circular orbit